# Android : multiple Markers on exactly same spot - GoogleMaps API 2.0

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I'm building an app that shows multiple Markers on map. Sometimes happens that in the exactly same spot (same lat & lng) there are multiple events, so multiple Markers. Now the events are overlapped so only one is shown to the user, and is possible to tap only that one. I thinked to group all events in the same spot in an only marker, but then it will be difficult to bind a marker with the right event.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: The best way to solve these kind of problems is to imagine you are telling someone else how to do the task.  If you get an event, get the lat lng and then place a marker on the map in that position, unless there is already one there - in which case, do nothing.

Comment: Thanks this could be a solution, but I'm not figuring out to handle InfoWindows, because I have an InfoWindow for each marker to show info about event. If I have only one marker for more events, how can I show the info for each event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sometimes happens that in the exactly same spot (same lat & lng) there are multiple events, so multiple Markers

That is unlikely to work well.

> I thinked to group all events in the same spot in an only marker, but then it will be difficult to bind a marker with the right event. What is the best way to handle this situation?

Have one `Marker` per location. If the user taps on a `Marker` that represents multiple events, either:

- Ask them which event they wish to examine, via a dialog, or
- Show them *all* events, such as via a `ViewPager` with tabs, or via a master-detail pattern UI (`ListView` of matching events, where taps on list entries bring up event details)